# WinForm having Janus Gridex hangs /freezes when Enter key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, janus, gridex

I have a windows form with Gridex Control which hangs when the '**Enter**' key is pressed when editing a row. The 'Enter' key triggers '**EndCustomEdit**' event and the win forms freezes.

Is there a way I can disable the triggering of '**EndCustomEdit**' event while the enter key is pressed?.

I tried implementing Gridex '**EnterKeyBehavior**' property inside '**EndCustomEdit**' event and tried setting it to **none** value but didn't see the required result.

```
this.gexContributor.EnterKeyBehavior = EnterKeyBehavior.None;
```

The other possibility i can think of is to create keyDown or KeyPressed event handler and handles the enter key behavior.

Plz let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It sounds like it could be getting hung-up on the UI thread when it goes to re-draw the UI after EndCustomEdit. Make sure there is no code running that has locked the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Following setting

```
this.gexContributor.EnterKeyBehavior = EnterKeyBehavior.None;
```

at the **designer.cs** level would fix this issue.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).